# Accessing the collection's image on a different page

Tags: shopify

I know that in Shopify when you make a collection you are able to submit an image to represent that collection and that you would get that image on the relevant collections page by doing {{ collection.image.src }} but does anyone know of a way of getting the same image onto a different page other than the collection page for that particular collection.

I thought maybe something like {{ collection[trousers].image.src }}

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors in there

- The `collection` variable is plural: `collections`
- The collection name needs to be in quotes

This snippet should work:

```
{{ collections['trousers'].image.src }}
```